# Push Notification:SHA-1 finger print

Tags: android, push-notification

For implementing push notifiation  as per android doc we need to create SHA-1  finger print for generating api key that is going to be used by application server.And for generating SHA-1 finger print we need keystore.

My question is in development time to test push notification can we use  the  same api key
created by using  keystore that is going to be  used for signing relaese  ready application.
Or  is it neede to create  api key  using  keystore with debug key.

Anyone please help  to get it clarified

Answer (score 0):

You can register multiple signing certificates with one API key.
Just add them line by line in the [API projects console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

E.g. add the fingerprint of your release certificate and the fingerprints of all the developer/debug certificates you have.